# Problem with mdf database after attached to SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a problem with a `.mdf` database for ETAP 19.01. I tried to attach its `.mdf` database on SSMS and it successfully attaches. But when I detach it and reopen the database with ETAP 19.01 it says that the application is unable to open the database. Anyone here knows what is wrong with that? Or has anyone here experienced similar failure when opening `.mdf` database with default apps after it has been attached to SSMS? Any answers is appreciated. Thanks.

btw, here is the error message :

[image: here is the error]

Comment: Can you post the entire error message verbatim.

Comment: What SQL Server **versions** are involved?? If you happen to attach this `.mdf` file to a **newer** version than from where it had been detached in the first place, you won't be able to "go back" and re-attach it to the older version of SQL Server, since it's been converted to the newer internal file structure when attaching.

Comment: i am currently using the newest SQL server, but when i use older SQL server the problem still persists...can you tell what will change after it has been attached to SSMS?

Comment: As far as I can determine ETAP 20 (newest) uses SQL Server 2012. If that is correct, you have effectively lost your ability to use that database with your version of ETAP. Now would be a good time to stop what you are doing and contact their support and your organization's support and come up with a plan to get any required systems back into working order. Alternatively you could try to migrate the database to the older version of sql server via scripting. That is an error-prone process for someone without experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out i installed a wrong version of SSMS...thx everyone for helping with my question :)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that you DETACHED the database. If the database is detached, an application won't be able to work with it.

Make sure you attach the database in SSMS before opening it in ETAP 19.

Comment: thank you for answering, but before that, my ETAP 19 could open its .mdf file without problems before i attached it to SSMS...it is right after i attach it to SSMS (and detatch it) i am unable to reopen it with ETAP 19..but i will try your solution first

Comment: i have tried your solution just now but it won't work at all

Comment: A few things to check: 1) Why are you attaching/detaching a database and are there any activities happening with the database in between ? 2) Once you know that the database is attached in SSMS, what is the error message that ETAP gives? 3) Can you confirm that credentials for connection used by ETAP are working?

Comment: If the suggestions helped you to answer the question, please mark them as Answer. Thank you!